# Do you think markup of jQuery mobile is semantically perfect, can I modify?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, semantic-markup

To make a simple list it uses too much code

3 `div` inside `li` and 1 blank `span`

```
<li data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-a">
<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
<div class="ui-btn-text">
<a href="footer-persist-a.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Persistent footer nav bar</a>
</div>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r"></span>
</div>
</li>
```

[image]

http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/#/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

and it also uses these attributes

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
```

Are these attributes of `ul` W3C valid?

So if I use jQuery mobile in a project is it necessary to follow it's only HTML? or can I modify to better way if possible and still use jQuery mobile.

Comment: Here's a hard truth: nobody cares about semantic markup in the mobile web.

Comment: @BoltClock - But actually mobile need less mark-up because Internet on mobile is costlier than Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** perfectly valid html **5**

I believe the extra elements are there to create good looking touch friendly controls and if you want to modify the source code, you'll have to change CSS and JavaScript, then test it on all devices jQuery mobile caters for (Apple/Android/Blackberry).

Do you have a problem with this sort of mark-up? Perhaps it may not be too SEO friendly and may not work in Internet Explorer prior to v9 but other than that it serves its purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't have any problem but my point is it's not semantically accurate and what if same presentation can be achieved with less code. This list item has 1 background image of arrow and gradient behind the text which can be made using CSS gradient and I just thought that can be made by only `<li class="class-name"> text </li>`

Comment: But if changing the html will lead to more work then I would use the existing code. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I see your point, but I think the extra elements are there mainly for corss-platform compatibility. If you could demonstrate a working example with less mark-up, you should suggest it to jQuery mobile.